# How to fetch list of objects with same phone number

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have an entity for `driving_info` with lot of fields but one of them is a phone number ( from which was ordered ).
What I am trying to do is to fetch all drives that were ordered from that number. But when I try to pass the int of `phoneNumber` I get

```
query did not return a unique result: 5; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 5
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 5; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 5
```

I actually want the list of results so that I can get a response of list of all drives that were ordered from that phone number.

My controller method is

```java
@GetMapping("/users/{phone}")
public List<User> getUserByPhone(@PathVariable int phone) {
   List<User> users= userService.findByPhone(phone);
   if(users == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("User not found with "+phone+" phone number");
    }
    return users;
}
```

And my DAO is

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public List<User> findByPhone(int phone) {
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query<User> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from User where phone=:phone",User.class);
    List<User> users = theQuery.getResultList();
        
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to correct your query in this way:

```
List<User> users = currentSession.createQuery(
   "select u from User u where u.phone = :phone",
   User.class
).setParameter( "phone", phone )
.getResultList();
```

Please note that as it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select):

> Even though HQL does not require the presence of a `select_clause`, *it is generally good practice to include one*. For simple queries the intent is clear and so the intended result of the `select_clause` is easy to infer. But on more complex queries that is not always the case.
>
> It is usually better to explicitly specify intent. Hibernate does not actually enforce that a `select_clause` be present even when parsing JPQL queries, however, applications interested in JPA portability should take heed of this.

Comment: setParameter was the missing piece, it was saying that parameter is not bound until it was not present.
I found it online and got it up and running but since you were kind enough to post that before me, I will accept your answer. Thank you SternK

Comment: Here is my solution

Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

  Query<User> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from User where phone= :phone",User.class);
  theQuery.setParameter("phone", phone);
  List<User> users = theQuery.getResultList();

Comment: Please note that it is generally good practice to include `select_clause` even though HQL does not require its presence. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `theQuery.list()` instead.

Comment: I tried that method as well, same result sadly.